# How to store a byte array to StackExchange.Redis?

Tags: redis, protobuf-net, stackexchange.redis, msgpack, zeroformatter

I want to use the `MessagePack`, `ZeroFormatter` or `protobuf-net` to serialize/deserialize a generic list and store it in Redis using the `stackexchange.redis` client.

Now I'm storing a JSON string with the `StringSetAsync()` method. But I can't find any documentation on how to store a `byte[]` in Redis.

Answer (score 26):

`StackExchange.Redis` uses `RedisValue` to represent different types of values stored in Redis and so it provides implicit conversion operators (for `byte[]` among others). Please read [StackExchange.Redis / Basic Usage / Values](https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/KeysValues#values) carefully as in the third sentence of that chapter you can find

> However, in addition to text and binary contents, ...

which basically means that you can use `IDatabase.StringSet()` to store a basic value (which Redis generally thinks of as a "string" as there are other types like sets, hashes, and so on) - be it string or an array of bytes.

```
        using (var multiplexer = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect("localhost:6379"))
        {
            byte[] byteArray = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06 };
            var db = multiplexer.GetDatabase();
            db.StringSet("bytearray", byteArray);
        }
```

Comment: (nods in appreciation)